# Best Way To Go Back To V2 Colors

Tags: highcharts

I love HighCharts but I really do not like the new color scheme in V3.

What is the best way to return to the V2 color scheme?

Thanks in advance!

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just specify they them using the [colors option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors)?

```
$(function () {

    var OldColors = [
       '#4572A7', 
       '#AA4643', 
       '#89A54E', 
       '#80699B', 
       '#3D96AE', 
       '#DB843D', 
       '#92A8CD', 
       '#A47D7C', 
       '#B5CA92'
    ]


    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        colors: OldColors,

        etc...
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mGFAg/50/).